# How to launch correctly a CGI http.server located in a subfolder in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Environment:**

Python 3.7.7

Windows 10 64bits

**Problem:**

I have my main script doing some stuff. I need to display a report of its activities.

I made a mini website which display the data activity.

I placed this mini website in a subfolder ‘/report’.

Inside this subfolder ‘/report’, I have the script Report.py which launch the http.server

My main script is executing this Report.py in order to open the mini website in a browser. Since 3 days I am working on it and I didn’t succeed to make it work.

**So this is how my code is organized:**

```
main.py
report/Report.py
report/index.py
```

**here is main.py:**

```
from report import Report
Report.StartReportTool()
```

**and here is what I tried inside the Report.py file and which error I get. These codes below are the content of method "StartReportTool()":**

**N°1:**

```
port=8888
address=("",port)
server=http.server.HTTPServer
handler=http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
handler.cgi_directories=["report"]
httpd=server(address,handler)
print(f"Report tool server started on port {port}")
webbrowser.open(f'http://localhost:{port}/report/index.py', new=2)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

**Error:** The browser open url ‘http://localhost:8888/report/index.py’display the source code of index.py instead of executing the script index.py

================================
**N°2** I edited the url pass to webbrowser.open

```
port=8888
address=("",port)
server=http.server.HTTPServer
handler=http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
handler.cgi_directories=["report"]
httpd=server(address,handler)
print(f"Report tool server started on port {port}")
webbrowser.open(f'http://localhost:{port}/index.py', new=2) #<= I change this line
httpd.serve_forever()
```

**Error:** The browser opens this URL ‘http://localhost:8888/index.py’ and displays this error message:

```
Error response
Error code: 404
Message: File not found.
Error code explanation: HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND - Nothing matches the given URI.
```

================================
**N°3**
I edited the folder pass to handler.cgi_directories

```
port=8888
address=("",port)
server=http.server.HTTPServer
handler=http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
handler.cgi_directories=["/"] #<= I change this line
httpd=server(address,handler)
print(f"Report tool server started on port {port}")
webbrowser.open(f'http://localhost:{port}/index.py', new=2)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

**Error:** The browser opens this URL ‘http://localhost:8888/index.py’ and shows this error message in the browser:

```
Error response
Error code: 404
Message: No such CGI script ('//index.py').
Error code explanation: HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND - Nothing matches the given URI.
```

I don’t know what else to try. Does anyone have any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is 'index.py'

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (notice the slash):

```
handler.cgi_directories=["/report"]
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to load index.py not index.html.

Comment: I have python code inside index.py. THat is why I can't open  index.html

Comment: Right, the browser can't interpret python though. You need to give him some HTML

Comment: The browser request index.py to server. Then server writes the HTML code when executing index.py and display it in the browser.